# How to avoid duplicating code on repetitive patterned column names with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table like this:

```
require(dplyr)
y = data.frame(a.foo=rnorm(10),b.foo=rnorm(10), a.bar=rnorm(10), b.bar=rnorm(10), a.baz=rnorm(10), b.baz=rnorm(10))
```

And I often end up doing something like this (simplified to just `+` in this example)

```
y %>% mutate(z.foo=(a.foo+b.foo),z.bar=(a.bar+b.bar),z.baz=(a.baz+b.baz))
```

Sometimes there are various of these and I wonder if there is a shorthand way using things like `matches` because the only pattern is that generally I want to do `z.* = a.* + b.*`. Is there an elegant way to express that in `dplyr` without hardcoding the cases?

Comment: In your case you could simply do `y[c(T,F)] + y[c(F,T)]` without any packages, but you example is very simple I guess.

Comment: Yea, I have other columns in there, and just want to apply this binary function across the pairs matching a regexp as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this via standard evaluation and `lazyeval`, although it might seem like a lot of work at first glance and I'm not sure *elegant* applies.

The idea is to use `interp` in a `lapply` loop to go through the suffixes of interest and set up a function for each matched pair of variables you have.

To avoid hard coding the suffixes, you could pull them out of the dataset.  This works in the simple case you have, but it might take more thought if your real data are more complicated.

```
suffix = unique(sub(".*\\.", "", names(y)))
suffix
[1] "foo" "bar" "baz"
```

Now the loop, making the simple function `'+'(x, y)` (aka `x + y`) in `interp`.  The variables for `x` and `y` are set via `paste`ing the appropriate suffix, all wrapped in `as.name`.

```
dots = lapply(suffix, 
                function(suff) interp(~'+'(x, y), 
                                    x = as.name(paste("a", suff, sep = ".")),
                                    y = as.name(paste("b", suff, sep = "."))))
dots

[[1]]
~a.foo + b.foo
<environment: 0x036bf4b8>

[[2]]
~a.bar + b.bar
<environment: 0x036c189c>

[[3]]
~a.baz + b.baz
<environment: 0x036c4c14>
```

Then just use `mutate_` with the list `dots` to calculate your new variables.

```
mutate_(y, .dots = dots)
```

Columns of interest look like:

```
   a.foo + b.foo a.bar + b.bar a.baz + b.baz
1     -2.7750933     2.2524274    0.52665909
2     -1.6001349     0.7894692   -0.13340202
3      0.8031004     1.1632274    0.46272597
4     -0.9941492     1.4346315   -0.06327656
5     -1.7558620     1.4079703   -1.14218434
6     -0.6322581    -1.5661146    1.40710596
7      0.4077698    -2.9227982    1.33316137
8     -0.2664580     1.5139438    1.95130283
9     -0.4476210    -0.7926471   -0.44932288
10    -0.6217235    -1.2043056   -0.19059357
```

To get the new names you'd need to add the use of `setNames`, again using `paste` to create the names based on the `suffix` vector.

```
mutate_(y, .dots = setNames(dots, paste("z", suffix, sep = ".")))
```

New columns:

```
        z.foo      z.bar       z.baz
1  -2.7750933  2.2524274  0.52665909
2  -1.6001349  0.7894692 -0.13340202
3   0.8031004  1.1632274  0.46272597
4  -0.9941492  1.4346315 -0.06327656
5  -1.7558620  1.4079703 -1.14218434
6  -0.6322581 -1.5661146  1.40710596
7   0.4077698 -2.9227982  1.33316137
8  -0.2664580  1.5139438  1.95130283
9  -0.4476210 -0.7926471 -0.44932288
10 -0.6217235 -1.2043056 -0.19059357
```

Answer (score 0):

As @aosmith mentions, you can use `lazyeval::interp` in combination with a work-around non-standard evaluation (`dplyr` function ending with `_`, see `vignette("nse")`) to help you there. In case you want to be more generic without having to hardcode the `+` operation (and maybe you have many columns to sum?), I would also use `contains` within `select` in order to apply directly your function to all relevant columns:

```
require(lazyeval)
suffix = unique(gsub(".*\\.", "", names(y)))
myNewColsValues = lapply(suffix, 
                         function(pattern) interp(~ select(y, contains(patt)) 
                                                  %>% rowSums, 
                                                  patt=pattern) )
y %>% mutate_( .dots = setNames(myNewColsValues, paste0('z.', suffix)) )
```